# Why isnt my "for" loop working for my expression?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r, g, b, y, rf, gf, bf;

    cout << "Insert three numbers stating values of red, green, and blue fish respectively at initial state:" << endl;
    cin >> r >> g >> b;
    while (r<=0 || b<=0 || g<=0) {
        cout << "Input invalid. All values must be above 0. Please reenter:" << endl;
        cin >> r >> b >> g;
    }
    cout << "Please enter how many years have passed since initial state:" << endl;
    cin>> y;

    while (y<=0) {
        cout << "Input invalid. Year must be 1 or higher. Please reenter:" << endl;
        cin >> y;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=y; i++) {
        rf = r + r * .10 - 100;
        gf = g + g * .15 - 100;
        bf = b + b * .05 - 100;
    }

    if (rf<0) {
        rf=0;
    }
    if (gf<0) {
        gf=0;
    }
    if (bf<0){
        bf=0;
    }

    cout << "After "<< y << " years there are:" << endl<< rf << " Red fish" << endl << gf << " Green fish" << endl << bf << " Blue fish" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Intro to comp sci student here. I am working on my term project and put in this "for" loop to do the selected expression a certain number of times (y). However when I compile and execute I always get the same result no matter what I put in for y. What did i do wrong here?

Comment: Could you please indent your code? Thanks.

Comment: And please wrap your lines so the code doesn't need a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: You are not using any values in your computation that are updated each for loop so you will always compute the same value each iteration. For example `rf = r + r * .10 - 100;` updates `rf` but you don't use `rf` in the computation.

Comment: Time to learn how to use debugger, I think.

Answer (score 2):

you are not accumulating `rf` they will always be calculated the same way, y times

Comment: How do i accumulate rf bf and gf?

Comment: @user3047757: See Mahmoud's or Josh's answer. I'm not sure which is right, but I suspect Josh's is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do what I think you are, this should work. You are performing the same calculation for rf, gf, and bf each time, since r + r *.10 - 100 will equal the same thing no matter how many times you do the calculation, because the value of r is not changing.

edit: also, for rf, gf, and bf you need float values since you are multiplying by percentages. Initialize them to 0 as well. (if it still doesn't work try making them all floats)

```
for (int i=0; i<=y; i++)
{
    rf = rf + r * .10 - 100;
    gf = gf + g * .15 - 100;
    bf = bf + b * .05 - 100;
}
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<=y; i++)
{
    rf += r * .10 - 100;
    gf += g * .15 - 100;
    bf += b * .05 - 100;
}
```

Comment: With these the results come out to be 0 for all three after one year even though they should be 10 15 and 5

Comment: change your rf, gf, and bf to floats

Answer (score 2):

I guess the for loop is doing it wrong check the correct one below:

```
for (int i=0; i<=y; i++)
{
    rf += r + r * .10 - 100;
    gf += g + g * .15 - 100;
    bf += b + b * .05 - 100;
}
```

You have to update rf, gf, and bf using += operator

Comment: With this edit, if i loop it one time the decimals are two times its original value? The results after one year should be 10 15 and 5 but i get 20 30 and 10 as if the percents were doubled. ?

Comment: one thing to keep in mind when coding in C/C++ is to always initialize your variables. In this case (unless i missed it) rf/gf/bf are declared but not initialized. So when doing the first time you do rf += r + r * .10 -100, the behavior is not quite defined.

Comment: As for your actual comment: the values are doubled because your for loop stops after 2 iterations and not 1 due to your i<=y. Use i<y instead

Comment: Yes that and removing all the rfs and replacing with just r solved the problem. Thanks everyone!!